# What is the correct says of `how to quickly remember 10^x to 2^y`

Tags: sentence-construction, proper-nouns

### My purpose

Know `how to quickly remember  10^x to 2^y` , or find a online tool can convert between them.

for example:

```
10^1 to 2^3(approximations) 
10^6 to 2^20(approximations) 
10^x to 2^y(approximations)
```

### My purpose comes out English problem

I don't know the proper words for this, how do I say it ?

In Chinese, we usually say `10的x次方` (`10's x power`)  to indicate 10^x , but direct translation (`convert 10 power to 2 power`) seems not correct and looks weird to me .

### What I tried

I don't know how to say that, so I choose a simple sentence `convert decimal to binary approximations`.  Searched google,  but the results (websites) are of the kind that always are providing tools used to

> convert `10`(decimal) to `1010`(binary)

Comment: '_10's powers_' is valid in English.

Comment: The canonical English version of `10^6` is _10_ ***to the power of*** _6_

Comment: Do you mean *convert log10 to log2*?

Answer (score 1):

Speaking

**10^1** is 10 to the first power

**2^3** is 2 to the third power

**10^6** is 10 to the sixth power

**2^20** is 2 to the twentieth power.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, as you suggested, "*[power](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_of_10)*" is a very valid usage in terms on Mathematics, even in English.

> **10 ^n** : 10 to the *'n'* th power.

Alternatively, I've heard the usage '*raised to*' also. I'm not a native speaker, so I'm not sure about the frequency of its usage.

> **10 ^n**: 10 raised to '*n*'

Comment: Even shorter, you can say "ten to the n".

Comment: Even though the question has already received two answers, I'm pretty sure that's not what the OP was actually asking.

Comment: This is what I could deduce from what he has posted. If he makes it cleared, I'm open to modifying the answer, as well as to take it down :)

Comment: Do you mean `convert 10 power to 2 power` is correct/nature saying in English ?   `convert 10 to the 'n' th power  to 2 to the 'm' th power approximately`,  this sounds even more strange ...

Comment: @Cookie Monster  Google search `10 to the 10` directly give the answer, that's a good knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

The other answers tell you how to express exponential notation, however if your question is how to *change* a base 10 exponent to a base 2 exponent, the verb is *to convert*.

> What is an easy way to **convert** from decimal to binary?
>
> You can easily search for an [online **conversion** tool](http://www.rapidtables.com/convert/number/decimal-to-binary.htm) that changes numbers from decimal to hexidecimal or binary.

You can also *express* something in decimal as a binary number.

> Is there an easy way to **express** a decimal exponential as a binary exponential.

Note: "Decimal" is equivalent to "base 10" and "binary" is equivalent to "base 2".